# Can I make an (absolutely positioned) element grow without linebreaks until certain width?

Tags: css

Consider these elements with tooltips:

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}
/*[data-tooltip]:hover::before {
  display: block;
}*/
[data-tooltip]::before {
  /*display: none;*/
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  z-index: 1; background: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% + 12px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
    /* the main thing */
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% + 2 * 10px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 6em;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 #ccc;
}
.content {
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.content_small {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.content_medium {
  padding-right: 1em; /* to emulate cells wider than the content */
}
```

```html
<div class="content content_small" data-tooltip="some text">some text</div>
<div class="content content_medium" data-tooltip="some text">some text</div>
<div class="content content_large" data-tooltip="some larger text">some larger text</div>
```

These 2 lines

```
width: calc(100% + 2 * 10px);
max-width: 7em;
```

are to control width of the tooltips. The first one is supposed to suppress linebreaks (without it ~each word will be on a new line), the second one is to limit the width.

The problem about this approach is the first one is based on the width of the element, not content of `data-tooltip` and because of that the tooltip of `.content_medium` element is wider than the content. So I'm looking for an alternative approach that would allow to make tooltips' width be adjusted to its content but until a width limit, after which line breaking should be used.

I wonder if this is possible with only CSS at all, or I have to use JS for this.

Could you propose such an approach?

Comment: _“The first one is supposed to suppress linebreaks (without it ~each word will be on a new line)”_ - I don’t see how this is supposed to make sense to begin with. If you do _not_ want “some text” to break into two lines, then how do you expect it to still have the same width as the actual content “some text”, if you add 10px padding to the tooltip on both sides …?

Comment: @04FS *how do you expect it to still have the same width as the actual content “some text”* why, it's `calc(100% + 2 * 10px)`, not `100%`, so padding doesn't interfere (but it may interfere in another approach, sure). See the snippet, it works fine with `.content_small`